# Can you use system restore entirely from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, system-restore

How do you use system restore using just the command line? I tried the Microsoft website however I only saw how to open the application from the command line.

How do you restore your Windows PC from a system restore backup without a graphical interface? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is Yes.

If you use a search engine to search for "Windows System Restore PowerShell", you will find that there are several PowerShell cmdlets for managing System Restore, including:

```
Checkpoint-Computer 

Restore-Computer

Disable-ComputerRestore 

Enable-ComputerRestore 

Get-ComputerRestorePoint
```

[Here is an article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2012/02/21/powershell-windows-restore.aspx) which will help you start off.